# node-gyp c++ leak test with valgrind

Tags: c++, node.js, memory-leaks, valgrind

Quite simply, how can I do a leak test for a node-gyp c++ module I've just written? Most of the imported c++ code has been tested in different projects, but I would like to make sure there are no leaks.

AFAIK, the only execution mode I've seen is via `node`:

```
var wv = require('./build/Release/word_vec.node');                                                                                          
var json = JSON.parse(require('fs').readFileSync('amazon.json', 'utf8'));                                                                   
var res = wv.convert_sparse(json, 5, 6, 0);                                                                                                 

var fs = require('fs');                                                                                                                     
fs.writeFile("output", JSON.stringify(res), function(err) {                                                                                 
    if(err) {                                                                                                                               
        return console.log(err);                                                                                                            
    }                                                                                                                                       
});
```

The function I want checked is `convert_sparse` which resides in `word_vec.cpp` and is compiled in `./build/Release/word_vec.node` or the equivalent debug sub-directory.